# Live search in laravel with AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

How can I create a search engine in my app with ajax request that will display the searched item on a table?

This is what I have in my controller, and it runs on every load and requires a full page load to show new results.

```
public function search() {
    $q           = Input::get('searchKeyWords');
    $users       = DB::table('users');
        $results = $users->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $q .'%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'. $q .'%')
        ->orWhere('password', 'LIKE', '%'. $q .'%')
        ->get();
    return View::make('users.search')->with('users', $results);
}
```

I am looking to switch from a full page load to just making an AJAX request that gets the data, so the page doesn't have to be completed reloaded. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: so what is your specific question?

Comment: When do you plan to call this function ?

Comment: how can i translate this method into ajax request so i dont have to reload every time i search for something...?

Comment: so it means it has nothing to do with laravel....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is quite broad as it stands, and it could benefit from some code that you have tried and maybe a more clear explanation of what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pjax can be the good solution for this. you can load the content via ajax request. URL will also be changed but the page itself will not be reloaded.

Following links may help you.

Simple pjax JS library
https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

pjax with laravel support
https://github.com/vtalbot/pjax